# Eclipse - JUnit5 Source not found - How to add JUnit5 source code?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit5

Where to find and how to add JUnit5 src.jar or src.zip into Eclipse to view the JUnit5 Source Code?

When I try to access the source code from JUnit on a JUnit package I get a 'Source not found' Message.

Where can I find the Source Code?

If found how can I attach it? Since in Eclipse > Java Build Path > JUnit5 > junit.jar > Source attachment > **is non modifiable** (won't let me edit it).

I could not find any info on this on either Eclipse or JUnit Website.

```
Info on Eclipse Version:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
```

Comment: I pinged the Eclipse IDE team on Twitter. Let's see if they respond. ;-) https://twitter.com/sam_brannen/status/973555384722968576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Maven or Gradle to pull in your dependencies on JUnit Jupiter, you can configure the Maven or Gradle Buildship plugins in Eclipse to automatically download the source JARs.

However, if you're just using a project that you created directly in Eclipse without Maven or Gradle build support, then I don't know how to attach the source JARs.

Comment: You have to have a version of Eclipse that provides explicit support for JUnit Jupiter. Eclipse versions starting with 4.7.1a have that support: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7.1a/#junit-5-support